# Есть ли плагин или можно ли как то сделать что бы в конце блока был комментарий класса?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Можно через emmet .test|c а хотелось бы что бы это было всегда на автомате.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю речь идет о [HTML End Tag Labels](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=anteprimorac.html-end-tag-labels), он кстати недавно начал поддерживать JSX.